Return entity and its parent (if exists)
My model represents categories. When my program runs it pulls all the categories from an SQLite database and puts them in a data grid.
Each category itself may have a parent but no parent is a parent of any other category (i.e. it's not an infinite upwards tree). The max is 1 level. If it has a parent I wish to return the information about its parent as well as itself. If it doesn't have a category then it would be blank in the category column.
Here is what my WinUi 3 program looks like. Where it says "Chicken | 1" I wish it instead to say "Chicken | Meat" because 1 is the primary key for the Meat category of which chicken is a sub category.

Model:
public class IngredientCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Parent { get; set; }

    public IngredientCategory(){}

    public IngredientCategory(int id, string name, int parent)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Parent = parent;
    }
}


You should be able to do this:
public class IngredientCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }          

    public IngredientCategory Parent { get; set; }
}

public class YourDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<IngredientCategory> IngredientCategories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<IngredientCategory>()
           .HasOne(c => c.Parent)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId)
           .IsRequired(false);
    }
}

Then you can Query:
dbContext
   .IngredientCategories
   .Select(x => new { CategoryName = x.Name, ParentCategoryName = x.Parent?.Name });

For adding Categories without Parents:
   dbContext.IngredientCategories.Add(new IngredientCategory 
   { 
       // Id should be auto generated
       Name = "Meat"
   }); 

For adding Categories with Parents:
   dbContext.IngredientCategories.Add(new IngredientCategory 
   { 
       Name = "Meat",
       ParentId = 2,  // When Id 2 is already existing
   }); 

